# Normal Distribution Question

Tags: normal-distribution

Could someone go over these calculations and tell me where I'm going wrong please. It's to do with normal distribution.

The question: In a factory, the packets of sweets produced are supposed to contain 1kg each. It has been found that the weights are normally distributed with mean 1.01kg and standard deviation 0.009kg. Find, to 1 d.p, the percentage of packets above the nominal 1kg weight.

So I need to find $P(Z>1)$

If I put it into the formula I get:

$$Z = \frac{1 - 1.01}{0.009}$$
$Z = - 1.1$ recurring

And I get a bit stuck here because to use my normal distribution chart, I need to make it so $P(Z < z)$, but its $P(Z > z)$ at the moment. Therefore I would just do $1 - P(Z < z)$. However, it's also a negative so I would have to do $1-P(Z < z)$ again.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that $1-(1-p)=p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $\Pr(Z \gt -a)$, where $a$ is a positive constant. By symmetry of the standard normal, 
$$\Pr(Z\gt -a) =\Pr(Z\lt a).$$
This should be directly available from your tables for the cdf of the standard normal.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot André!

Answer (score 2):

p(x>1)=p[z>(x-u)/s] where x=1, u=1.01, and s=0.009   by substituting the values and simplifying,                         p(x>1)=p(z>-1.11)  from the normal table, z-values are taken about 0 whether +tive or -tive they've the same value. Note that z-value for either +tive or -tive infinity is 0.5                                  Therefore, p(z>-1.11)=0.5+0.3665=0.8665          if you 're confused over this, consider finding the area between -1.11 to infinity on a number line where each of them are measured from 0                              -1.11 to 0= a(e.g)             0 to +infinity = b            -1.11 to +infinity = a+b where a and b are the values of -1.11 and +infinity respectively from the standard normal table.